# Mapping a sub-component within a child-component repeatedly through an array returned by API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, state

I'm having a problem with mapping components. Frankly, I'm not experienced enough with React to code like a God. I'll walk you through my problem in increments so you guys fully understand what's happening.

Annex 1.1
This is my child component, as you can see, I am using React useState and useEffect hooks to update my state when I pull an array from an API. No big deal, no problem here, just regular stuff.

```
function Financeticker() {

const [crypto, setCrypto] = useState([]);
const classes = useStyles();

useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get(
            `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/totalvolfull?limit=10&tsym=USD&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
        )
        .then((resCrypto) => {
            console.log(resCrypto.data.Data);
            setCrypto(resCrypto.data.Data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}, []);
```

Annex 1.2 Here is a function that functions as a subcomponent (fetus component, lol jk) in my child component. If it gets confusing, you'll probably understand at Annex 1.3 but basically the response of the API  returns an array of [10] objects. Now, I want the subcomponent to render 10 times (using .map) and pull each property from the API (I.E. `{crypto.CoinInfo.FullName}`) The problem is that I get an error stating "Cannot read property "FullName" of undefined.

```
const cryptoTicker = crypto.map(() => (
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography
                        className={classes.companyName}
                        color='textSecondary'
                        gutterBottom
                    >
                        {crypto.CoinInfo.FullName} <---- CANNOT READ PROPERTY "FULLNAME" OF UNDEFINED
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </Grid>
    ));
```

Annex 1.3 Here is the child component's return method that basically calls the `{cryptoTicker}`function within the `Ticker` component. In effect, we are doing; Step 1: Pulling data from an API. Step 2: rendering subcomponent X amount of times (in this case, 10 times) within the `Ticker` child component. Step 2.1: pulling that data from the array returned by the API and plonking the data down on the subcomponent.

```
    return <Ticker>{({ index }) => <>{cryptoTicker}</>}</Ticker>;
}

export default Financeticker;
```

I hope this question was structured well enough to get an answer. Thanks dev community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are mapping over an *array*, but you never specified the item. The problem is here in the first line:

```
const cryptoTicker = crypto.map(() => (
```

Change this to

```
const cryptoTicker = crypto.map((item) => (
```

Then you should be able to display the name like this:

```
    {item.CoinInfo.FullName}
```

Full code:

```
const cryptoTicker = crypto.map((item) => (
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography
                        className={classes.companyName}
                        color='textSecondary'
                        gutterBottom
                    >
                        {item.CoinInfo.FullName} <---- CANNOT READ PROPERTY "FULLNAME" OF UNDEFINED
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </Grid>
    ));
```

I am making an educated guess, but I think that you had the problem at all, was that you had no loading state and so on the first render, `crypto` was an empty *array*, but you tried to access a property of it, as it was an *object*.

Comment: Woah, that worked. However, I'm currently rendering 10 components. I have an image [here](https://imgur.com/a/0ul8CgY) It's currently rendering 10 child components each with 1 subcomponent. I'm trying to render 1 child components with 10 subcomponents. Is there any flaw in my programming logic?

Comment: and I can't believe I didn't see the .map argument was empty. Damn.

Comment: Honestly, to answer this, I would have to see how the code is interconnected. You get ten components because, you have ten elements in the array. Is there maybe another map somewhere? You could set up a codepen if that is not too much work for you.

By the way, do you use a linter? Something like `eslint` can help you spot such mistakes easily.

Comment: Alright, give me a few moments. Thanks for helping a junior out. Everything works fine in the console. hold on I'm gonna set up Codepen

Comment: Here is a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-frost-xxcrq?file=/src/components/Financeticker.js) of my repository. You have to drag the viewing screen since it renders if the viewport is large enough. Have a look

Comment: After hours of staring at the screen, I figured out that perhaps it is rendering the components the way it should but it's doing it vertically. Is there anyway we can force it to render horizontally.

Comment: I just tried to debug a bit and my only advice to you is to take a closer look at what *react-ticker* does. Because it seems to repeat the results of the map. I couldn't find another place which looks suspicious. Also, I would advice that you implement some kind of loading state when the api call is underways, so that the user knows whats happening.

Comment: Yeah it's bare bones for now. React-Ticker calls function cryptoTicker as it only accepts functions. if I did `<Ticker>{cryptoTicker}</Ticker>` then it doesn't work. However if I remove `<Ticker>` and just render `{cryptoTicker}` in a div then it renders fine horizontally. really weird

Comment: I finally solved it. Instead of calling  `cryptoTicker` directly. I basically created another object which contains the map function originally from `cryptoTicker`. `cryptoTicker` would only content the grid components and would call `cryptoContent` which is the object that contained the map function. In effect, `<Ticker>` would call `cryptoTicker` and `cryptoTicker` would call `cryptoContent` needless to say, staring at the codebase for 3 days in 6 hour increments did its job lol

Comment: Good Job.

>staring at the codebase for 3 days in 6 hour increments did its job lol

Yeah, that is what coding is all about ;-) At least in the beginning, it goes down to 2 days with 4 hour increments in time :-)

Comment: HAHAHAHA. Yep. I'm really passionate about coding. I'm really thankful to stack overflow and the supportive dev community for helping newbies out. Thanks again for answering my query.